# class template and member function template with requires

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a template class called Speaker, with a template member function called speak. These both have a requires clause. How do I define the member function outside of the class in the same header file?

```
// speaker.h

#include <concepts>

namespace prj
{
    template <typename T>
    requires std::is_integral<T>
    struct Speaker
    {
        template <typename U>
        requires std::is_integral<U>
        const void speak(const Speaker<U> &speaker);
    };

    // what do I put here?
    const void Speaker<T>::speak(const Speaker<U> &speaker)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for defining template members of class templates are the same in principle as they were since the early days of C++.

You need the same *template-head(s)* grammar component(s), in the same order

```
template <typename T> requires std::is_integral_v<T>
template <typename U> requires std::is_integral_v<U>
const void Speaker<T>::speak(const Speaker<U> &speaker)
{
        // code
}
```

The associated constraint expression and `template <...>` form the *template-head* together.

---

As an aside:

- `const` qualified return types are redundant in the best case, or a pessimization in the worst case. I wouldn't recommend it (especially over `void`).
- I'd also recommend using concepts (`std::integral`) if including the library header, not type traits (`std::is_integral`) that may or may not be included. The concepts allow for the abbreviated syntax, which is much more readable:

  ```
  template<std::integral T>
  template<std::integral U>
  ```